# H2 Schema initialization. Syntax error in SQL statement

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I have a spring boot application and I trying to initialize some data on application startup.

This is my application properties:

```
#Database connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test_db
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.schema=schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=schema.sql


#Hibernate configuration
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
```

This is schema.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Person` (
  `id`         INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `age`        INTEGER  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
```

and data.sql

```
INSERT INTO `Person` (
  `id`,
  `first_name`,
  `age`
) VALUES (
  1,
  'John',
  20
);
```

But I got 'Syntax error in SQL statement' on application startup:

```
19:08:45.642 6474 [main] INFO  o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000476: Executing import script '/import.sql'
19:08:45.643 6475 [main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: CREATE TABLE Person (
19:08:45.643 6475 [main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE PERSON ( [*]"; expected "identifier"
Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE PERSON ( [*]"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
```

I can't understand, what's wrong with this SQL.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this code. Remove `PRIMARY KEY(`id`)` and execute it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Person` (
    `id`         INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `first_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     `age`        INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 10):

This error results from the structure of the `CREATE TABLE` declaration.

It will be the result when you have an **extra comma in the end of your SQL declaration**--no column declaration following the comma. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Person` (
  `id`         INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `age`        INTEGER  NOT NULL,     --note this line has a comma in the end
);
```

That's because `CREATE TABLE` expects a list of the columns that will be created along with the table, and the first parameter of the column is the `identifier`. As you check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp), the column declaration follows the structure:

```
identifier datatype <constraints> <autoincrement> <functions>
```

Thus, in your case, as [@budthapa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2489973/budthapa) and [@Vishwanath Mataphati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13941329/vishwanath-mataphati) have mentioned, you could simply remove the `PRIMARY KEY(id)` line from the `CREATE TABLE` declaration. Moreover, **you have already stated that `id` is a primary key** on the first line of the column definitions.

In case you do not have a statement as the PRIMARY KEY declaration, **be sure to check for the extra comma following your last column declaration**.

Answer (score 9):

I was add below in to application.properties and it work for me

> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions = true

Comment: This worked for me. I'm not sure what it does, but it's related to H2 memory database, if you are using one.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, as you have used **`Table_name`**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person (
    id        INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
     first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     age        INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was missing the semicolon at the end of create table statement.

Answer (score 1):

What helped in my case was removing single quotes from the table name in my insert query

I had to change this:

```
INSERT INTO 'translator' (name, email) VALUES ('John Smith', 'john@mail.com');
```

to this:

```
INSERT INTO translator (name, email) VALUES ('John Smith', 'john@mail.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

You set auto increment id, so you can't insert new record with id.

```
Try INSERT INTO `Person` (
  `first_name`,
  `age`
) VALUES (
  'John',
  20
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same issue. I fixed that with these `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.charSet=UTF-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor=org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor
```

Some issue with multi-line and default encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when one of my fields in the JPA Entity had the same name as SQL reserved keyword (`FROM`).

Before:

```java
@Entity
public class Event {

    ...

    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime from;

}
```

Fix:

```java
@Entity
public class Event {

    ...

    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime fromDate;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I was using an integer field called "year"