# SpringBoot JPA data.sql failed

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i wanna sql script to load my data.
but my SQL script dosen't work. 
and i don't know why error is caused.

my data.sql is

```
insert into person('id', 'name', 'age', 'blood_type') values (1, 'martin', 10, 'A');
```

and my test code is

```
 @Test
void curd() {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("john");
    person.setAge(10);
    person.setBloodType("A");

    personRepository.save(person);

    List<Person> result = personRepository.findByName("john");

    assertThat(result.size()).isEqualTo(1);
    assertThat(result.get(0).getName()).isEqualTo("john");
    assertThat(result.get(0).getAge()).isEqualTo(10);
    assertThat(result.get(0).getBloodType()).isEqualTo("A");
}
```

and my domain Person class is

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NonNull
private String name;

@NonNull
private int age;

private String hobby;

@NonNull
private String bloodType;

@Valid
@Embedded
private Birthday birthday;

private String job;

@ToString.Exclude
private String phoneNumber;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@ToString.Exclude
private Block block;
```

}

and my error is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/D:/CCC/intellij_ex/mycontact/build/resources/test/data.sql]: insert into person('id', 'name', 'age', 'blood_type') values (1, 'martin', 10, 'A'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO PERSON('id'[*], 'name', 'age', 'blood_type') VALUES (1, 'martin', 10, 'A')"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
insert into person('id', 'name', 'age', 'blood_type') values (1, 'martin', 10, 'A') 

Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/D:/CCC/intellij_ex/mycontact/build/resources/test/data.sql]: insert into person('id', 'name', 'age', 'blood_type') values (1, 'martin', 10, 'A'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO PERSON('id'[*], 'name', 'age', 'blood_type') VALUES (1, 'martin', 10, 'A')"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
insert into person('id', 'name', 'age', 'blood_type') values (1, 'martin', 10, 'A') 

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO PERSON('id'[*], 'name', 'age', 'blood_type') VALUES (1, 'martin', 10, 'A')"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
insert into person('id', 'name', 'age', 'blood_type') values (1, 'martin', 10, 'A')
```

I digging this error issues so long time. but i didn't find out.
plz help me

Comment: review this question's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267245/h2-schema-initailization-syntax-error-in-sql-statement

Comment: @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) <-- I tried this already but it doesn't run.

Comment: Could you plz share the data.sql and schema.sql

Comment: omg...I found the problem. I was using " ' "instead  of " ` " . thanks for ur help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.sql code

```
insert into person('id', 'name', 'age', 'blood_type') values (1, 'martin', 10, 'A');
```

have to change

```
insert into person(`id`, `name`, `age`, `blood_type`) values (1, 'martin', 10);
```

Comment: or even drop the backticks

Answer (score 0):

Your Id already generated as below.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

so you can try again the edited SQL query.

```
insert into person('name', 'age', 'blood_type') values ('martin', 10, 'A');
```