# Syntax error in SQL statement - Expected Identifier

Tags: sql, h2

I have a springboot application and I would like to connect my application to the H2 database. Below is my schema.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee 
(
      id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
      first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
      last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
      email VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
      posit VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
      mobile INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Below is is my application.properties.

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false

spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.schema=schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=schema.sql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update


logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

However, I face the following issue:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "create table employee (id bigint not null auto_increment, email varchar(255), first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), mobile integer, posit varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine[*]=InnoDB"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement.

May I know what is the issue and how do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the schema you're sharing is not the same as the one that has the error, could you check that and share the corresponding one?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  posit VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  mobile INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Because in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267245/h2-schema-initailization-syntax-error-in-sql-statement) the error is in the schema, and the schema you shared works perfectly on [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

I'm not a pro in sql so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you have a syntax error at this place of your `CREATE` statement:

```
engine[*]=InnoDB
```

h2 doesn't know what to do with the `engine` keyword. It won't work.

To **fix it** you should check your `CREATE` statement of the `employee` table and remove the `engine[*]=InnoDB` part.
If you're also using the script for the setup of your MySQL database and you need this engine part, then you can set the following line on top of your file:

```
/*! SET storage_engine=INNODB */;
```

This should make it work with H2 and MySQL.

[Here's also a google group where the same problem appeared](https://groups.google.com/g/play-framework/c/V4Ky2C06yww).